# How do I switch the font back to previous in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, font

The font changed in El Capitan and, consequently, in some of my programs, the font is off of the screen or cut off. How do I change the font back to the previous font, before El Capitan?

**Examples:**

*Eclipse Project Properties Dialog*
[image: From Eclipse Properties Dialog]

*Eclipse Find Dialog*
[image: Eclipse Find Dialog]

*Firefox Context Menu*
[image: From Firefox Context Menu]

Comment: Curious… The new [San Francisco](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(2014_typeface)) font was supposed to have the same sizing as the previous system font to avoid this very problem. **Can you list some of the apps having the problem, and post screenshots?** By the way, Apple provides this [WWDC presentation about this new family of system fonts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-804/) for those interested in technical details.

Comment: Next time I encounter it I'll take some screenshots and post back. Also, thanks for the detailed links!

Comment: I added some screen shots. I'll add more as I encounter them. BTW I do like the font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try installing a third party application called [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html).

TinkerTool is an application that gives you access to additional preference settings Apple has built into OS X. This allows to activate hidden features in the operating system and in some of the applications delivered with the system. You can download the product free of charge.

You will find the new available options in System Preferences and thus you can change the font in the *Font* tab as in the figure below:

[image]

Comment: That looks amazing. It looks like there are a lot of settings for the system font. The alignment issues seem to happen in dialogs and pop ups but I'm not 100% sure. Since each is specific to an area of the OS maybe one of these settings will fix it across the board. Thanks